# Why wouldn't distributions use a cross-platform service manager?

Tags: services, deployment

I use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) for my services on production servers. I also recently switched to MacOS and, for services that I need for development, instead of a OSX's service manager, proposed by brew (launchd?), I decided it's better to just use Supervisor here also.

So I wondered. Why wouldn't different distributions (and operation systems) just use Supervisor or develop an alternative that would fit their needs that would be same in terms of being cross-platform? This seems like a great simplification of things, because:

- while config-files for the same service would differ in path or environment, they would still be mostly the same in principle, making it easier to port
- it's always great when you have very same tool across different distributions, operation systems and environments

If you think the question is silly because there are too much things that are in principle wrong with supervisor to be OS-level service manager replacement, please point out at least some of them.

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in webmin: http://www.webmin.com/

Comment: @muru sorry, that's not quite what I wanted to talk about